# Selecionando elementos desabilitados

Tags: css, seletores

Preciso diferenciar a visualização de uma select box onde há um elemento selecionado por default, porém o mesmo não pode ser selecionado pelo usuário (como se fosse um placeholder de um input normal), mas quero estilizá-lo, tentei utilizar algo como `option:disabled` do CSS que encontrei em alguns sites, porém, não surtiu efeito algum, como posso resolver meu problema ?

EX:

```
<select>
  <option disabled selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Vou colocar como código executável, pelo meu entendimento funcionou. Após você selecionar você não consegue selecionar o option com valor = 1 mais, seria isso mesmo?

Comment: não, seria o option usando um disabled, pois pode ser qualquer um, mesmo com um valor diferente, e não se faz necessário colocar um executável, já que não possui um CSS ou javascript para testar.

Comment: E não é questão de selecionar o item, é questão de selecionar o elemento desabilitado e estilizá-lo com o CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é isso que você está procurando?

```css
option[disabled]{
  color:red;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```